# How to get default value from web.config in webapi attribute routing parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to get the attribute routing default parameter value from web.config?

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/books/locale/{lcid:int?}")]
        public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksByLocale(int lcid = <Read from web.config>) { ... }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Not at this point, cause this values are defined during compile time. In the method GetBooksByLocale you can get the value from web.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot, this lcid default variable must be an const value,

you can assign null, and do some logical inside controller to assign this variable with web.config value.

Hope this help

Comment: Yes, I am doing that currently. But wondered if there was some option. Thank you.